# Evaluating the limit for high degree polynomial

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

This appears like a nice highschool question but I cant see it through; $$\lim _{x\to 2}\frac{3x^3-5x^2+2x-8}{4x^4-11x-42} $$

The high degree polynomial does not allow to find any common factors....so how do we do this?

Comment: If you put $x=2$ in the denominator, either you find that equals $0$, or not. For the first case, you are sure there is a factor of $x-2$ in the denominator by remainder theorem. For the second case, simply substitute $x=2$ to the whole fraction.

Comment: Synthetic division.

Comment: thanks to all those who commented...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Notice the value $x$ is tending to see if that is factor of those two polynomials(Otherwise You'll just have to substitute the value!)

$$\frac{3x^3-5x^2+2x-8}{4x^4-11x-42}=\frac{(x-2)(3x^2+x+4)}{(x-2)(4x^3+8x^2+16x+21)}$$

\begin{align}&\lim _{x\to 2}\frac{3x^3-5x^2+2x-8}{4x^4-11x-42}\\&=\lim _{x\to 2}\frac{3x^2+x+4}{4x^3+8x^2+16x+21}\\&=\frac{18}{117}=\frac{2}{13}\,.\end{align}

Comment: how did you see that?

Comment: Did you check your synthetic division?  Your denominator is wrong; it should be $16x$, not $13x$. And shame on you if you made this mistake by comying DSinghvi's answer.

Comment: thanks, that's what Ive been looking for...

Answer (score 4):

You can always use the Euclidean algorithm to find the gcd of the polynomials.

Comment: That's just what I was going to say!

Answer (score 2):

We see that in trying to plug in $x=2$ (the limiting value of $x$), both the numerator and denominator are $0$.

That is $2$ is a zero of both the numerator and the denominator.  So by the Factor Theorem, $(x-2)$ is a factor of both the numerator and the denominator.  Knowing this we can use (synthetic) division to find the other factors.

Answer (score 2):

In a problem like this, unless $x-2$ is a factor of the denominator, the fraction can be evaluated merely by pluggin in $x=2$ on top and bottom.  Since they gave you the problem, you can be pretty sure that the denominator will be zero at $x=2$, and that clues you that one factor is $(x-2)$.

Now divide numerator and denominator by $(x-2)$ to get:
$$
\frac{3x^2+x+4}{4x^3+8x^2+16x+21}$$
and now you can plug in $x=2$ to get 
$$\frac{18}{117} = \frac{2}{13}$$